# How i can get a drawable res, if only i get the image from a url

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a External Library and this need a Int, the int is the resource

```
   banners.add(new DrawableBanner(intResource));
```

But i only have the image in a url and i did this

```
  Glide.with(MyActivity.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(mPhotoProfile);

   Drawable d = mFotoPerfi.getDrawable();
```

This gives me the Drawable but it does not allow me to place, it needs the resource in the form of "Integer" and not "Drawable"
How can I somehow pass it to the "Resources" and get it there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A photo from Firebase is not a resource. Resources are packaged in your APK, from the `res/` directory in your project.

Comment: Yes i know but, its not possible download the photo and get it in a resource?

Comment: @Dskato: No. I repeat, resources are packaged in your APK, from the `res/` directory in your project. Files that you download on a device cannot become resources.